# How to save a file from database to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Question is rather simple, and somewhat pointless I understand, but still...

Database is on the server, of course, and I need an action that will when initiated grab that file from database and save it to a folder that is in my `AppSettings["Active"]` configuration property.

Basically,

```
public ActionResult Activate(int id)
{
    Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);

    var activeProjectData = project.XML; // project.XML returns byte[] type
    //For download (not in this method of course) i'm using something like return File(activeProjectData, "text/xml"); and that works ok

}
```

Now I want to save that file to `AppSettings["Active"]` path. Not to sure how to go about it. I've tried using `System.IO.File.Create()` but that didn't quite turn out well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: File from the database? Do you mean the file is stored in binary form as data inside the database?

Comment: Yes, file is as binary inside database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a FileStream and use it to write the data:

```
string fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Active"];
using(var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write) )
{
    fs.Write(project.XML, 0, project.XML.Length);
}
```

If you don't need more control than that, there is a [simple helper method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) on the `File` class:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, project.XML);
```

Comment: This looks quite promising, I knew it was something on `File` class... Just couldn't it figure it out spot on. Will try it, thanks.

Comment: I'd use `File.OpenWrite(fileName)` instead of creating the FileStream manually, it basically just wraps the `new FileStream` but it looks cleaner. :)

Comment: I used `File.WriteAllBytes()` works like a charm and still looks clean :) Thanks driis!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a FileStream

```
SqlCommand ("select fileBin from SomeTable", connection);
byte[] buffer = (byte[]) command.ExecuteScalar ();
connection.Close();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\filename.pdf", FileMode.Create);
fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
fs.Close();
```